# Handling a limited resource in rest WEB API 2

Tags: c#, .net, web-api, singleton

I have developed a restful WEB API 2 (C#, .NET 4.7) for an internal integration project. In my API's backend, I need to use a vendor's dll in order to process the provided input.

The vendor's dll is written in C, and it has a limitation that, there cannot be more than 8 initialized instances at the same time.

Since my REST API can be called multiple times concurrently, there is a risk that I may hit the 8 instances limit during a busy time. (My API is not public. There is a little chance that this can happen. But still, I need to stay safe.)

To prevent this, I was planning to keep the current count of the running instances on a thread-safe singleton variable. And if I can maintain the increment/decrement logic where I initialize the C dll, I can stay safe.

Since a REST API is stateless, is it a good practice to use a static thread-safe approach to implement this? Or there could be better approaches like using server cache, Application State ( Application["VariableName"] = "Value" ), or even a flat file.

And I need to add that, a database is not an option at my situation.

Comment: Putting a restriction on the number of concurrent calls to your API does not magically make the API stateful, just like using a database for persistent storage doesn't make a REST API stateful.

Answer (score 1):

You should wrap initialization and subsequent calls to the vendors lib with a [Semaphore](http://dotnetpattern.com/threading-semaphore) to avoid too many instances. Any request coming in when the specified limit has been reached will automatically be queued.

Answer (score 1):

What you really need is an [Object Pool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_pool_pattern) with a pool size of 8.  It's reasonably easy to implement an object pool using the [BufferBlock](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh160414.aspx) class.